# how to show the selcted value selected in CakePHP selectbox

Tags: php, cakephp-2.3

following is the code that i have used to show the values in selectbox . but how to show the value selected the below code is not working for me..

```
$currencyName = Array
(
    [$] => US Dollar 
    [$] => rdcyhgv976
    [€] => Euro
    [£] => UK Pound
    [¥] => Japanese yen
    [a] => a
    [b] => test
)

$selected=Array
(
    [Currency] => €
)

<?php 
echo $this->Form->input('SystemUser.Currency', array('type'=>'select','options'=> $currencyName, 'selected'=>$selected['Currency'], 'label' => false, 'div' => false, )); 
?>
```

can anybody tell where I am wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
<?php 
echo $this->Form->input('SystemUser.Currency', array('type'=>'select','options'=>    $currencyName, 'default'=>$selected, 'label' => false, 'div' => false, )); 
?>
```

Change "selected" to "default".

Comment: tried this as well.. but still facing the same issue